# How to change the tkinter icon

Tags: python, tkinter

i have looked at other questions and they do not help so i need some help changing the tkinter icon
i followed the guide at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iconphoto-method-in-tkinter-python/
I am making a lightweight python editor like IDLE
Still a work in progress
i am using python 3.8.3rc1

```
from tkinter import Tk, scrolledtext, Menu, filedialog, END
import tkinter.scrolledtext as ScrolledText
#main window
root = Tk(className = " PYPad+ ")
photo = PhotoImage(file = "/assets/PYPad+.ico")
root.iconphoto(False, photo)
textArea = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(root, width=135, height=80)

#
#FUNCTIONS
#
def openFile():
    file = filedialog.askopenfile(parent=root, mode='rb', title=' Select File ')
    if file != None:
        contents = file.read()
        textArea.insert('1.0', contents)
        file.close()
def  saveFile():
    file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w')

    if file != None:
        data = textArea.get('1.0', END+'-1c')
        file.write(data)
        file.close()


#menu options
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
fileMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label=" File ", menu=fileMenu)
fileMenu.add_command(label="New")
fileMenu.add_command(label="Open", command=openFile)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Save", command=saveFile)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Print")
fileMenu.add_separator()
fileMenu.add_command(label="Save and Exit")
helpMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label=" Help ", menu=helpMenu)
helpMenu.add_command(label="Help")
helpMenu.add_separator()
helpMenu.add_command(label="About")
textArea.pack()



#keeps window open
root.mainloop()
```

when i run this i get this error code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PYPad+.py", line 5, in <module>
    photo = PhotoImage(file = "/assets/PYPad+.ico")
NameError: name 'PhotoImage' is not defined
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? I presume you're getting an error, so please add that to the question.

Comment: You have only imported a few specific names from the `tkinter` module.  That's a perfectly valid way of writing code - but it means that you need to remember to add each new thing you need from the module to the `import` statement, such as `PhotoImage`.

Comment: Built-in `PhotoImage` does not support ico format even though it is correctly imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

root.iconbitmap('/path/to/ico/icon.ico')
```

Comment: Hey @Adil Shirinov i tried your code and i got another error code but it is too big to put in a comment

Comment: @TuttiFrutti you do not have to put the whole comment.A few last lines would be enough

Comment: ok @Adil Shirinov                                                                                                
```return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "/assets/PYPad+.ico" not defined```

Comment: @TuttiFrutti I think its related to file path. You need to have .ico in the same folder or dictionary as your script because python only searches in the current dictionary or you could put in the full pathname.

Comment: if you need the full error code here it is [link](https://imgur.com/H1DTRVR)

Comment: @TuttiFrutti   try this
img = PhotoImage(file='your-icon')
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, img)

Comment: I tried that solution and got this [error](https://imgur.com/Wpi0NFn)

Comment: @TuttiFrutti adding from tkinter import PhotoImage
will fix the error

Comment: @Tutti Read up on [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)